# Is this pointer always a runtime construct

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, this, constexpr

I am learning about the `this` pointer in C++. And i came across the following [statement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2) from the standard:

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`, except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is being evaluated as part of `e`;

---

I do not understand the meaning of the above quoted statement. I thought that the `this` pointer is a **runtime construct** and so it cannot be used in compile-time contexts. But the above statement seems to suggest otherwise in the mentioned contexts. **My first question is** what does it mean. Can someone give some example so that i can understand the meaning of that statement.

---

I tried to create an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/9cE7f6h99) to better understand the meaning of the statement by myself but the program did not work as expected(meaning that it gave error while i thought that it should work according to the quoted statement):

```
struct Person 
{
    constexpr int size()
    {
      return 4;
    }
    void func()
    {
            int arr[this->size()]; //here size is a constexpr member function and so "this" should be a core constant expression and arr should not be VLA
    }
    
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9cE7f6h99)

In the above program, i thought that we're allowed to use the expression `this->size()` as the size of an array(which must be a compile time constant) because `size` is *constexpr* and so the quoted statement applies and so the program should compile. Also, since `size` is *constexpr* `arr` should not be VLA. But to my surprise, the `arr` seems to be VLA and the program also doesn't compile in msvc(because msvc don't have vla i think). So **my second question is** why doesn't the quoted statement applicable in the above example and why is `arr` VLA? I mean `size` is constexpr so `arr` shouldn't be VLA.

Comment: _except **in** a constexpr function_. Is `Person::func` constexpr?

Comment: did you miss the double negation perhaps? "An expression e is a core constant expression **unless** [...] would evaluate `this`, **except** in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor". `this` is not constant expression. `this` in a constexpr function or consexpr constructor is

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Making `Person::func` constexpr doesn't work either. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/szfo86bof)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't think that i missed the double negation. Although it is a possibility. Perhaps an example would clear the concept. That is why i was trying to write an example by myself. As asked in my question, can you make one example that shows this. Maybe if i were to use return something from insdie `size` using `this` then the example would've worked. But i don't know what to return in order for it to work.

Comment: constexpr runs "runtime stuff" at compile time. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: *"Making Person::func constexpr doesn't work either*" - But not for using `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to use `this` in a core constant expression is to call a constructor (and use it in the constructor) or call a member function on an existing object.

> `this` except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor ***that is being evaluated as part of `e`;***

(emphasis added)

In your attempt, the constant expression should be `this->size()`, but `Person::func` (the function `this` appears in) is not being evaluated as a part of that expression.

An simple example of what this allows:

```cpp
struct S {
    int i = 0;
    constexpr S(int x) {
        this->i = x;
    }
    constexpr int get_i() const {
        return this->i;
    }
};

// `this` used in constructor
constexpr S s{7};
// `this` used in `S::get_i`
static_assert(s.get_i() == 7);
static_assert(S{4}.get_i() == 4);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hea8cvcxW

Comment: why does this not work then https://godbolt.org/z/h9xj6xjx3 ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's the same reason the original doesn't work: `this` is being evaluated inside the constructor, but the constructor is not being evaluated as part of the constant expression.

Comment: @Anya It might be easier to think of the function being passed a hidden `T* this` argument and so it doesn't work for the same reason `constexpr void f(int x) { int arr[x]; }` doesn't work. I've changed the example to use `this` in a constructor as well.